# count records grouped into ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in my db called students with a column age along with other columns. I need to count students in each age range e.g. give me count of students with age between 0-5, 6-10,11-15 onward. Can I get this with single query or do i need to use BETWEEN clause in loop.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

This can also be taken as employee-salary relation. It can be changed to count employees with salaries in different ranges e.g. 1000k to 1500k etc.

Comment: probably should answer something before down voting it

Comment: I dont see the reason for the downvotes, I guess the reasons are "you didn't try yourself" but meh

Comment: you should post what you've tried yourself as part of the question. it will help people understand exactly what your struggling with. you'll get downvotes if it looks like your using SO as a querywriting service

Answer (score 1):

i dont think there is a function that will group the ages into your ranges or buckets. so you'll have to do that manually and then group the data.

```
select
case when age < 5 then '0-5' 
when age < 10 then '6-10'
when age < 15 then '11-15'
...
...
end as agerange
count(studentID)
from students
group by agerange
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a case and between the given ages (mine is just for an example), and then group by that.

```
select  case    
       when age between 0 and 20 then ' 0-20'  
       when age between 21 and 41 then ' 21-41'  
       when age between 42 and 62 then ' 42-62'  
       when age between 63 and 83 then ' 63-83'  
       when age between 84 and 104 then ' 84-104'   
    end as `range`, count(*) as `users`
from users group by `range`
```

I haven't been able to test it, but it should work :),else post the error and we try to fix it from there